# R GGPLOT - Add Averages of Each Series Contained in Facet Wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, average, facet-wrap

I have a dataset described as follows: I used 3 different standards, that I loaded 3 different times into the test apparatus where I took 10 measurements for each combination of standard & loading. I have been able to plot the data where I depict each loading as a different series and I do a facet wrap based on the standard. I now want to add the average of each loading for each standard to the chart and I cannot seem to do so.

My data first (LatexStandards_GammaSummary):

```
structure(list(Standard = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0.5 µm", "1 µm", "4 µm"), class = "factor"), 
    Loading = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("L1", "L2", "L3"), class = "factor"), 
    Gamma = c(0.66716, 0.67899, 0.67286, 0.67527, 0.67327, 0.67396, 
    0.68518, 0.66993, 0.65695, 0.67583, 0.68428, 0.68807, 0.68862, 
    0.67403, 0.68282, 0.69051, 0.68571, 0.67531, 0.68146, 0.68367, 
    0.68348, 0.68344, 0.68768, 0.68189, 0.68253, 0.6836, 0.68388, 
    0.68645, 0.67551, 0.67897, 0.62186, 0.63639, 0.62981, 0.63896, 
    0.61639, 0.62586, 0.6226, 0.63984, 0.63112, 0.63279, 0.61764, 
    0.63829, 0.62712, 0.62563, 0.62233, 0.63423, 0.62621, 0.62251, 
    0.6287, 0.6375, 0.62774, 0.64823, 0.62692, 0.63093, 0.6223, 
    0.62713, 0.62279, 0.63341, 0.63451, 0.63072, 0.61586, 0.71059, 
    0.7198, 0.57358, 0.66188, 0.7624, 0.71269, 0.74395, 0.75922, 
    0.70551, 0.535, 0.59343, 0.62455, 0.72823, 0.65101, 0.56216, 
    0.5248, 0.54717, 0.6283, 0.63807, 0.53681, 0.54385, 0.58027, 
    0.69051, 0.70548, 0.61578, 0.65215, 0.68302, 0.72091, 0.58527
    )), .Names = c("Standard", "Loading", "Gamma"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-90L))
```

The code I use to produce the original facet wrap ggplot:

```
# input data
inpdata <- LatexStandards_GammaSummary

# basic plot set up
plotout<-ggplot(data=inpdata,aes(x=Loading,y=Gamma))

# data sets
dataset1<-geom_point(aes(color=Loading), 
                     position = "jitter")

wrapon<-facet_wrap(~Standard)

# axis labels
xlbl <- xlab("")
ylbl <- ylab("g")

# theme mods
basetheme <- theme_bw()

  # x axis
theme_xaxis <- theme(
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
  )

number_format_xaxis <- ""

  # y axis
theme_yaxis <- theme(
  axis.title.y=element_text(family="GreekC",size=14)
)

number_format_yaxis <- function(x){format(x,digits=1,nsmall=1,scientific=FALSE)}
scale_yaxis <- scale_y_continuous(labels=number_format_yaxis,limits=c(0.4,0.9))

  # legend
theme_legend <- theme(
  legend.position = "bottom",
  legend.margin = unit(-0.5,"cm"),
  legend.key = element_blank(),
  legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
  legend.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "plain")
)

  # wrapping items
theme_wrapping = theme(
  strip.background = element_blank(),
  strip.text = element_text(size = 14)
)

  # panel items
theme_panel = theme(
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
)


plotout<-plotout +
  dataset1 +
  wrapon +
  xlbl +
  ylbl +
  basetheme +
  theme_xaxis +
  theme_yaxis +
  scale_yaxis +
  theme_legend +
  theme_wrapping +
  theme_panel

plotout
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely be best served by generating the summary data yourself, then plotting it. Using `dplyr`, here is an approach to calculate the averages:

```
avgLines <-
  inpdata %>%
  group_by(Standard, Loading) %>%
  summarise(Gamma = mean(Gamma))
```

Which gives:

```
  Standard Loading    Gamma
1   0.5 µm      L1 0.672940
2   0.5 µm      L2 0.683448
3   0.5 µm      L3 0.682743
4     1 µm      L1 0.629562
5     1 µm      L2 0.628016
6     1 µm      L3 0.630468
7     4 µm      L1 0.696548
8     4 µm      L2 0.603272
9     4 µm      L3 0.631405
```

Then, we can add this to the plot object you generated, setting the range of the segment you want to include (the `facet_wrap` from your plot object is applied here as well):

```
plotout +
  geom_segment(
    aes(y = Gamma
        , yend = Gamma
        , color=Loading
        , x = as.numeric(Loading) - 0.5
        , xend = as.numeric(Loading) + 0.5
    )
    , data = avgLines)
```

[image]

(Of note, much of the `theme` setting you included is not required for a minimally working plot -- you may have gotten quicker responses if you had trimmed the example down to just the portions relevant to what you wanted to generate.)

Comment: Thanks Mark, your code solved it for me. I appreciate the tips for formatting in the future as well!